# Как скачать html файл таким какой он есть

Tags: php

У меня на первом сервере лежит html файл, там обычная страница, с html и javascript кодом, и в js код вставлена php переменная.

Получается код html файла выглядит примерно так:

```
<html>
    <div>...</div>
    <script>
        window.location = "<?=$url;?>";
    </script>
</html>
```

Мне нужно этот файл сохранить на второй удаленный сервер с помощью php.

Я делаю так:

```
file_put_contents('folder/page.html', file_get_contents('https://site.ru/folder/page.html'));
```

В итоге на втором сервере появляется нужный мне html файл, но уже с таким содержанием:

```
<html>
    <div>...</div>
    <script>
        window.location = "";
    </script>
</html>
```

То есть не вставляется `<?=$url;?>`

P.S. Мне нужно чтобы в `window.location = ""` было не значение переменной **$url** а сама переменная чтобы присутствовала.

Comment: `$url = 'link'` => `window.location = <?= $url ?>`
посмотрите что покажет `<?php var_dump($url) ?>`

Comment: @InDevX так мне не нужно чтобы было `window.location = link`, мне нужно чтобы осталось ` window.location = "<?=$url;?>";`

Comment: зачем вам такими глупостями заниматься? 
между серверами файлы так не передаются

Comment: Когда вы делаете file_get_contents от обращается к вашему web-серверу и через него получает файл, как будто он был открыт из браузера. И конечно php там выполняется и подставляет переменную. Вот если бы вы делали `file_get_contents('/var/www/.../page.html'` т.е. указывали бы что берете файл с диска, а не через web-сервер, то его содержимое бы оставалось как есть.

Comment: Вам Максим Степанов дал рабочий код, а Mike точно изложил суть вашей проблемы :) Комбинируйте эти два ответа и будет профит )))

Answer (score 2):

Надо так надо:

```
$ftp = ftp_connect(FTP_HOST, FTP_PORT, FTP_TIMEOUT); // Создаём идентификатор соединения (адрес хоста, порт, таймаут)
$login = ftp_login($ftp, FTP_LOGIN, FTP_PASS); // Авторизуемся на FTP-сервере
ftp_pasv($ftp, true);// Пассивный режим
ftp_chdir($ftp,'folder'); // Меняем директорию
ftp_get($ftp, 'page.html', 'page.html', FTP_BINARY); // Качаем файл
ftp_close($ftp); // Закрывает соеденение
```

Можно еще отключить программно пхп интерпритатор в заданой папке перед скачиванием, а потом включить его обратно.

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Сервера не предназначены для того, чтобы отдавать исходники серверного кода.